# Access Update query doesn't update the data

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

This is the simplest update possible.

Access front-end, SQL back-end, linked tables.

```
UPDATE Available SET Status = 'New'
WHERE ((SerialNumber)='HAJ1376');
```

Runs with no errors, but returns 1 record showing 'Used'

```
SELECT [Status], * FROM Available
WHERE SerialNumber =  'HAJ1376';
```

also returns 'Used'.

Note that it doesn't matter if I do the update or the select by the string SerialNumber or the numeric ID.

Running the same query from SSMS changes the data properly.
This seems to be true for any field on any table. I can't update anything from Access.

This system is working fine in production, just failing on my development machine.

I went back to a prod backup and it still happens, so shouldn't be any changes I made to the database. Same with old versions of the code.

I tried dropping and recreating the connection to the table, rebooting, stopping and restarting SQL, repairing Office.

The connection string is

```
DRIVER=SQL "Server;SERVER=WORKPC\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=mydatabase;Network=DBMSSOCN;Trusted_Connection=No"
```

Differences:

- prod is using full SQL whereas I'm using express.
- the database is local instead of on a dedicated machine.
- I'm using accdb whereas prod is accde.

> Access 365, v16.0.13801.21072, 64 bit
> MS-SQL Server 2017, 14.0.1000.169, Express Edition, 64-bit
> Windows 10 Home 10.0, X64, Build 19042

Comment: I believe it is reading the correct record since I can change the value in SQL and see it in Access.

Comment: `Trusted_Connection=No` and no UID/PWD details? Does the guest account have permissions to update?

Comment: If you open the linked table can you edit a row of data? check this first and see if the linked table is allowing updates. If the linked table from the Access UI does not work, then your updates will also not work.  So try editing a row by just double clicking on that linked table - see if edits are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

In a quick test, the access query designer for a non-passthrough update query generated

```
UPDATE dbo_Available SET dbo_Available.Status = "Used"
WHERE (("SerialNumber"='HAJ1376'));
```

Which caused Access to send the following to SQL Server to fetch the affected key values:

```
SELECT "dbo"."Available"."SerialNumber" FROM "dbo"."Available" WHERE NOT((0 = 0 ) )
```

It returned no results, so affected 0 rows.  It's not well documented, but I don't see anywhere where Access (JET) SQL uses `"` for delimited identifiers.  So looks like Access query designer wierdness/bug/limitation.

But updating the SQL of the update query to

```
UPDATE dbo_Available SET dbo_Available.Status = 'New'
WHERE SerialNumber='HAJ1376';
```

worked.  Access first ran

```
SELECT "dbo"."Available"."SerialNumber" FROM "dbo"."Available" WHERE ("SerialNumber" = 'HAJ1376' )
```

then an RPC call to

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=1
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 varchar(200)',N'SELECT "SerialNumber","Status"  FROM "dbo"."Available"  WHERE "SerialNumber" = @P1','HAJ1376'
select @p1
```

to update the row.

Comment: So it looks like the issue was that the original query referenced the SQL Server Express table name rather than the default linked table name in Access (i.e., that begins with dbo_). Is that right?

Comment: `"SerialNumber"='HAJ1376'` makes no sense and isn't in the question. `[SerialNumber]='HAJ1376'` would work.